# R + GGPLOT2: Strange behavior with facets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a hard time understanding why the use of direct references with $ impacts the result of qplot with facets...

Why don't I get 5 dots aligned at (0,0) with this code?

```
data(Orange)
qplot(circumference-Orange$circumference, age-Orange$age, data=Orange, facets = ~Tree)
```

Comment: I could spend a while digging around in the sources, but the precise code causing this wouldn't be very enlightening. The point is that `qplot` simply isn't expecting you to mix standard and nonstandard evaluation in this way.

Comment: ...i.e. the tldr in baptiste's linked answer.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to search better next time. One may wonder why the tool does not error out when the unreliable combination of inputs is used.